# Reverse HTML Layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I will try to keep this as short and specific as I can.

This is what I need to display:

```
-----------------------------------------
#div1
-----------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
#div2
-----------------------------------------
```

This is how I need the HTML structure to be:

```
<div id="div2">...</div>
<div id="div1">...</div>
```

The reason I need the second div to be higher in the HTML structure is because when the page is printed in Firefox, I have to use fixed position for an image that is contained in "div2". If "div2" isn't at the top of the structure, the image will be printed on the second page, and therefore cannot be moved to the first page using fixed position (as far as I know).

I cannot for the life of me think how I can do this with CSS2 (maybe CSS3?). I also looked into "Any Order Column" but I don't think that will work since I'm dealing with rows, not columns.

Any help would be appreciated :)

**Edit:** #div2 cannot be positioned absolutely because #div1 needs to be able to collapse, and therefore #div2 needs to follow.

Comment: I still don't see a practical case in which you can use this. If you have to make this kind of change to accommodate for something else, it's time to change that something else. And in any case, you can just swap their contents with Javascript if you need to.

Comment: Are the elements fixed heights?

Comment: If the image in div2 is fixed-positioned, why does it have to be first? Can't you specify left and right properties for fixed positioning?

Comment: You can use absolute positioning for the divs, unless you need them to float? You can always use print css to override styles before they are printed.

Comment: If you know what the size of the divs will be, use absolute positioning to move div2 below div1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can use css3 `display:box` property for this. Write like this:

```
.outer{
   -moz-box-direction: reverse;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    display: -moz-box;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/phSfD/2/

Comment: It turns out that your method works better for me in this case :) Thank you very much @sandeep

Comment: +1, that's pretty cool. It's probably noting that the -moz stuff here reflects an [older version](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/) of a W3C working draft. The more [recent version](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) is entirely different, so it might be more appropriate to call this browser-specific css than css3.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

HTML:

```html
​<div class="outer">
    <div class="a"> [div a] </div>
    <div class="b"> [div b] </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
.outer { position:relative; }
.a { position:absolute; top:100%; }
```

​Test it out: http://jsfiddle.net/phSfD/1/

The benefit of this approach is you don't need to know the sizes of either element for it to work.

This works because the height of the outer element is determined by the height of its contents. Since div A is absolutely positioned, it doesn't affect the height of its container, so the container's height is the same as div B's height. Setting A's `top` to `100%` (of the container's height) means it will appear just below the container (and therefore just below div B).

Comment: This way it's impossible to place something after `outer` container since it would be overlapped by its absolutely positioned child element.

Comment: No problem. @MaratTanalin If you like you can substitute `margin-top` for `top`, it will not affect the layout of the page as much.

Comment: Absolutely positioned element is removed from normal flow anyway.

Comment: It turns out that @sandeep CSS3 method works better for me in this case. I got in some problems using absolute because I needed the body to follow the collapsing div :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to set absolute positioning of the two divs.  You'll need to have a parent with `relative` position and then set the absolute position of the two divs: div1 above the div2.

When you do so, remember to indicate in the `<style>` tag that these styles only apply to the on-screen rendering and provide a separate set of styles for printing, so that on print div would would appear below div2.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `position: fixed` on an element, it is positioned relative to the browser window, irrespective of its container.

So, this

```
#div1 img{ position: fixed }
```

and this

```
#div2 img{ position: fixed }
```

will render the same result. You can write them in any order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table-*-group` properties for vertical reordering of blocks of arbitrary height (dynamically resized in particular):

```
<style>
#example {display: table; width: 100%; }

/* Will display at the bottom of pseudo-table */
#block-1 {display: table-footer-group; }

/* Will display in the middle */
#block-2 {display: table-row-group;    }

/* Will display at the top */
#block-3 {display: table-header-group; }
</style>

<div id="example">
    <div id="block-1">First</div>
    <div id="block-2">Second</div>
    <div id="block-3">Third</div>
</div>
```

Works in all browsers including IE8+ (there is a small limitation in IE8).

For IE6/7 (if they do matter), elements can be swapped with JavaScript.

For details, see my [article](http://tanalin.com/en/articles/css-block-order/).